# How can I make the volume audible only on the left headphone?

Tags: audio, debian

Instead of 50/50 I want 100% on the left side of my headphones. How can I do this?

My OS is Debian Squeeze, and the laptop I have is a Thinkpad T61.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using alsa, you can do it with something along these lines in `~/.asoundrc` (or `/etc/asound.conf`):

```
pcm.card0 {
    type hw
    card 0
}
pcm.!default {
    type route
    slave.pcm card0
    slave.channels 2
    ttable.0.0 0.5
    ttable.1.0 0.5
    ttable.0.1 0
    ttable.1.1 0
}
```

I am basing this on http://alsa.opensrc.org/Talk:.asoundrc#Converting_stereo_to_mono_sound, there are a bunch of other examples there too.

Answer (score 1):

Does [wmix](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/wmix) work for you?

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to mix L+R into a single mono channel and then route that through just the left output.  Does wmix do that?

Comment: @Matt, I don't think it supports mixing the two channels into a mono stream. The Balance/Mute options can be used to turn off one channel. To 'downmix' from two to one channel, one would probably need to use a transcode (like ffmpeg -ac 1), I guess.

Comment: @Matt, Oops, I think we edited together -- I changed my initial comment where I thought 'balance' control was required to the one above about the time you answered back :-)

Comment: @nic I thought something like that had happened ;)